# Unexpected behavior of macro

Tags: c++, macros

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define f(a,b) a*b
using namespace std;
int main()
{cout<<f(2*2,3*2);
 return 0;
}
```

Outputs 24 while

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define f(a,b) a*b
using namespace std;
int main()
{cout<<f(2+1,3+1);
 return 0;
}
```

outputs 6.

How can one explain such hectic behavior of macros? I use code blocks.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macros are a simple text substitution mechanism. In your example, you have the following macro:

```
#define f(a,b) a*b
```

When you use that macro, the text `a*b` is substituted for the macro call, replacing `a` and `b` with whatever you used as parameters.

In your first example, `f(2*2,3*2)` becomes `2*2*3*2`, which does what you expect and outputs 24. However, in your second example, `f(2+1,3+1)` becomes `2+1*3+1`, which is interpreted as `2+(1*3)+1` and thus outputs 6.

You can fix this by defining the macro differently:

```
#define f(a,b) ((a)*(b))
```

Notice the extra set of parentheses. This ensures that the macro is evaluated before anything else in the expression. The extra parentheses around `a` and `b` ensure that the parameters are evaluated first.

Comment: Your fix doesn't help, more correct is `#define f(a,b) ((a)*(b))`.

Comment: Ah, right, forgot about that detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Macro are text replacement so your second snip-set becomes:

```
cout<<2+1 * 3+1
```

which is parsed

```
cout<< 2 + (1 *3) + 1
```

use function instead of macro in your case:

```
int f(int a, int b) { return a * b; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Priority of operation can change with macros. In your example, it does not send 3 and 4, it literally send 1+2 and 1+3, it expands like this:

```
1+2*1+3
```

However, this kind of things does not really belongs to a macro. If you have c++11, you can use constexpr:

```
constexpr int f(int a, int b) {
    return a*b;
}
```

If you want better runtime performance with runtime values and c++11 is not an option, you could force to inline the function:

```
inline int f(int a, int b) {
    return a*b;
}
```

I

Your question is one of the reasons macros are evil. Whenever you can, don't use it and use them only when it's the only solution.

Comment: Note, `inline` is generally just a hint - it will not force the function to be inlined. (In this specific case it probably would though.)

Comment: Yes, and omitting inline does not imply the compiler won't inline it. It's up to the optimizer to do it's job properly, and forcing the through macros may just prevent the compiler to optimize the code.